# Unity3D Configurable Joint component accessing through GetComponentInChildren

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a capsule and a sphere connected by a Configurable Joint. I move the player using the capsule rigidbody and the sphere acts as a caster wheel(like a unicycle with suspension).

As the sphere is a child of the capsule, I am using GetComponentInChildren to try and access the Configurable Joint's, Y Drive's, Position Spring (float value).

I got lost trying to google this problem.

Here is the relevant code, everything in `//Comment` does not work:

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Rigidbody rb;
    public float moveSpeed = 10f;
    public float distanceGround;
    public bool isGrounded = false;
    public bool isCrouch = false;


    void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        distanceGround = GetComponent<Collider>().bounds.extents.y;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Movement();
    }

    private void Movement() 
    {
        float inputX = Input.GetAxis("LStickHorz");
        float InputZ = -Input.GetAxis("LStickVert");
        float multiplier = 1f;

        if (!Physics.Raycast (transform.position, -Vector3.up, distanceGround + 1.5f))
        {
            isGrounded = false;
            print("IN AIR.....");
        }
        else
        {
            isGrounded = true;
            print("....onGround");
            //Debug.DrawRay(?,?, Color.red, 1.25f);
        }

        if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, -Vector3.up, distanceGround + .2f))
        {
            isCrouch = true;
            print("VVVVVVVVVVVVVV");
            //ConfigurableJoint cj = gameObject.GetComponentInChildren(typeof(ConfigurableJoint)) as ConfigurableJoint;
            //set y spring value
            //cj.yDrive.positionSpring = 50f;

        }
        else
        {
            isCrouch = false;
        }

        if (!isGrounded)
        {
            multiplier = .2f;
        }

        if (isCrouch)
        {
            multiplier = .2f;
        }

        Vector3 moveVector = new Vector3(inputX * multiplier, 0.0f, InputZ * multiplier);

        //if ()

        rb.AddForce(moveVector * moveSpeed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with your first comment, the function `Debug.DrawRay()`. If you look at the documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html) it will tell you all parameters of the function and show you an example. For this function, the first two parameters are position and direction:

```
Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.up * 5, Color.red, 1.25f)
```

The second issue is you cannot set the `positionSpring` field directly. You will need to store a reference to the `yDrive` in another variable, change the value of `positionSpring`, then set `yDrive` to the temp variable:

```
// Get the COnfigurableJoint component
ConfigurableJoint cj = gameObject.GetComponent<ConfigurableJoint>();

// Grab a reference to the JointDrive
JointDrive jd = cj.yDrive;

// Set the value of positionSpring here
jd.positionSpring = 50.0f;

// Apply the changes you made to the yDrive back to the ConfigurableJoint
cj.yDrive = jd;
```

Comment: @RRDAPHNE No problem. Since this solves your issue, could you click the tick icon for my question?